# I have added two buttons addOption and removeOption and i have written jquery for that but remove button is not working

Tags: jquery, html

This is my ftl page.

```
[<form action="questionDetail" method="post">
        <div class="outerDiv">
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="font">${question.question}</textarea>
            <input type="hidden" id="questType" value="${question.type}" />
            <ul id="list">
               <#list question.options as option>
                    <li class="font">
                        <#if question.type == 0>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="" />
                        <#elseif question.type == 1 || question.type == 2>
                            <input type="radio" value="" />
                        </#if>
                        <textarea rows="4" cols="100" >
                        <#if option ??>${option}</#if>
                        </textarea>
                    </li>
                </#list>
            </ul>
            <input type="button" id="addOption" class="button" value="+" /><label class="opt">Add Option</label>   
            <input type="button" id="removeOption" class="button" value="-" /><label class="opt">Remove option</label>
            <p><input type="submit" id="updateMCMO" class="button updateButton btn1" value="Update"/></p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And this is my jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $(document).on('click','#addOption', function(){
             if($('#questType').val() == 0){
                 $("#list").append('<li><input  type="checkbox" value="" /> <textarea rows="4" cols="92"></textarea></li>');
             }else {
                 $("#list").append('<li><input  type="radio" value="" /> <textarea rows="4" cols="92"></textarea></li>');
             }

         });
         $(document).on('click','#removeOption', function() {
             $('#list').each(function(){

             if($('#questType').val() == 0){
                 {
                     $(this).closest('li').remove();
                 }

             }
             else{
                 if($(this).find('input\[type=radio\]').is(':checked')){
                     $(this).closest('li').remove();
                 }
             }
             });
          });
        });
```

Am able to add more options but i stuck in removing it . Am not getting how to remove those Options. Please help out of this.

my removeOption button is not working please can anybody tell me where i am going wrong..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing option you are iterating over `#list` which from your html seems to be the `ul` with id list. So `$(this).closest('li')` returns nothing. Change the `#removeOption` click handler lke following and it should work.

```
     $(document).on('click','#removeOption', function() {
         $('li').each(function(){

         if($('#questType').val() == 0){
             {
                 $(this).remove();
             }

         }
         else{
             if($(this).find('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')){
                 $(this).remove();
             }
         }
         });
      });
```